# reshaping dataframe two columns into one column and two rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following df that I would like to reshape:

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Jack'],
                   'trip places': ['UK,UK,UK', 'US,US,US', 'AUS,AUS,AUS'],
                   'Trip code': ['UK322,UK454,UK4441', 'US664,US4544,US44', 'AUS11,AUS11,AUS11']

                   })

df6
```

Looks like:

```
    name    trip places     Trip code
0   Sara    UK,UK,UK        UK322,UK454,UK4441
1   John    US,US,US        US664,US4544,US44
2   Jack    AUS,AUS,AUS     AUS11,AUS11,AUS11
```

I want to add a new column lets say `df6['total-info']` and merge the current two columns `trip places` and `Trip code` in two rows per name, so the output will be like this:

```
    name        total-info
0   Sara        UK,UK,UK 
                UK322,UK454,UK4441
1   John        US,US,US
                US664,US4544,US44
2   Jack        AUS,AUS,AUS
                AUS11,AUS11,AUS11
```

I tried to do so by many methods grouping/stack/unstack pivot .. etc but all what I tried does not generate the output I need and I am not completely familiar with the best function to do so. I also used concatenation but it generated one column and added all the two columns comma separated values altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and specify the new column name:

```
df7 = (
    df6
        .set_index('name')  # Preserve during reshaping
        .stack()  # Reshape
        .droplevel(1)  # Remove column names
        .reset_index(name='total-info')  # reset_index and name new column
)
```

`df7`:

```
   name          total-info
0  Sara            UK,UK,UK
1  Sara  UK322,UK454,UK4441
2  John            US,US,US
3  John   US664,US4544,US44
4  Jack         AUS,AUS,AUS
5  Jack   AUS11,AUS11,AUS11
```

Or if name is to be part of the multi-index append name and call [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)
after `stack` and `droplevel` instead:

```
df7 = (
    df6
        .set_index('name', append=True)  # Preserve during reshaping
        .stack()  # Reshape
        .droplevel(2)  # Remove column names
        .to_frame(name='total-info')  # Make DataFrame and name new column
)
```

```
                total-info
  name                    
0 Sara            UK,UK,UK
  Sara  UK322,UK454,UK4441
1 John            US,US,US
  John   US664,US4544,US44
2 Jack         AUS,AUS,AUS
  Jack   AUS11,AUS11,AUS11
```

Comment: try rename and pd.wide_to_long ~